# AngularJS $transclude undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have written a custom directive in AngularJS. And I have to use isSlotFilled method of $transclude. The JavaScript of the directive:

```
define(['../directives-module'], function (directivesModule, $scope, $transclude) {    
    directivesModule.directive('news', function() {
        return {           
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            transclude: {
              'heading': 'heading',
              'content': '?content'
            },
            scope: {
                'cmsContent': '@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'directives/news.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
                console.log($transclude.isSlotFilled(content));
            },
        };
      });    
});
```

I have tried to output a console.log() to check the method works. The console.log() above does not work, saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSlotFilled' of undefined

Actually, I have to use this method on the HTML file of the directive. The file news.html contains:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="largeText shadow1" ng-transclude="heading"></div>
    <div class="mediumText shadow2" ng-transclude="content"
         ng-class="{'hide' : $transclude.isSlotFilled(content)}">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see in the ng-class, it will hide the div if the content slot is not filled. However the condition here inside ng-class always returns false. I'm sure I am missing something at injecting $transclude. What should I do to properly use this method from the news.html?

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: @VishalRajole It's 1.5.0

Comment: You're not injecting $transclude to directive, whatever it is. Is it a module? Service? The question says nothing on this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're attempting to do using your module system but in any case: `$transclude` is not a service but a function that's injectable to directive and component controllers. The same goes for `$scope`.

The link function gets called with the transclude function so you may use it directly. Also remember to put quotes around `content`.

```
define(['../directives-module'], function (directivesModule) {    
    directivesModule.directive('news', function() {
        return {           
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            transclude: {
              'heading': 'heading',
              'content': '?content'
            },
            scope: {
                'cmsContent': '@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'directives/news.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
                console.log(transclude.isSlotFilled('content'));
            },
        };
      });    
});
```

To access it in a template you can add it as a property to the scope. You can do that in the link function if you want:

```
function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
    console.log(transclude.isSlotFilled('content'));
    scope.transclude = transclude;
}

// Or maybe
function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
    console.log(transclude.isSlotFilled('content'));
    scope.hasContent = transclude.isSlotFilled('content');
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I could not for the life of my figure out how to get hold of that `transclude` function

Comment: it's not my question but I'm sure @Faruk Yazıcı can help you